# nodeschool learnyounode node.js make it module

Tags: node.js

Im trying to solve this exercise , here is my code

module.js

```
module.exports = function (one, two, callback) {
    var fs = require("fs");
    var path = require("path");
    var konc = "." + two;
    fs.readdir(one, function (err, list) {
        if (err) return callback(err);
        var list = list.filter(function (x) {
            return path.extname(x) == konc;
        });
        callback(null, list)
    })
}
```

and world.js

```
var module=require("./module.js");
module(process.argv[2],process.argv[3],function(err,list){
if(err) return console.log("error",err);
list.forEach(function(v){
    console.log(v)
})
})
```

when i try to verify it , it says i FAILED = 
? Submission results did not match expected!
? Did not use an additional module file, you must require() a module to help sol
ve this exercise

## FAIL

Your solution to MAKE IT MODULAR didn't pass. Try again!
altough i did include module , where is the problem?

Comment: The error message says what you need to do: `you must require() a module to help solve this exercise`. You have to `require` your module in `world.js`.

Comment: its in world js , i wrong copy pasted it sorry.

Comment: Are you passing the correct file to `cli`? Like, are you running `learnyounode verify world.js`?

Comment: yes , i am running learnyounode verify world.js